# VMware Converter: "FAILED: Unable to find the system volume, reconfiguration is not possible."

Tags: windows-xp, vmware, vmware-converter

VMware converter keeps barfing with this error (after hours of processing) while trying to convert the current XP system into a VM.

Anybody knows what might be going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [thread](http://boardreader.com/thread/FAILED_Unable_to_find_the_system_volume_5kog0X5n9x.html) :

> Your boot.ini has a line that
>   Converter can not handle :
>   `C:\CMDCONS\BOOTSECT.DAT="Microsoft
>   Windows Recovery Console" /cmdcons`
>   Remove it and run the "configure
>   machine" option of Converter.

In any case, it would help if you posted the contents of your `C:\boot.ini` file.

Answer (score 1):

if you have recovery partition on your drive, it was converting over. When you de-selected this option from converter app telling it not to move over, it prompts you with IF YOU REMOVED THIS YOUR VM WON'T BOOT, ignore it and should be fine.  but if you can post log file here it will be more helpful to resolve your issue:)